# php can i pass variable in link in session

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I want to pass a variable with `link` with session but variable that i get is from loop in database, it's always override to last one. So i can have any solution with it?

this is my code:

```
    <tr>
        <td class="noborder_dtable"><a href="business/index.php"><?php  echo $row_com['name_kh'];?></a></td>
        <td class="noborder_dtable"><a href="business/index.php"><?php echo $row_com['name_en'];?></a></td>
        <td class="noborder_dtable"><?php $_SESSION['id']=$row_com['id'];?></td>
    </tr>
```

Edit: my problem in `business/index.php` when i `echo` i can see only last `id` of all id while i click on any `name`, i mean i want click on name that it's pass session it of those name to next page.

Comment: Btw, it's `$_SESSION` and not `$_SISSION`. Plus, remember to include `session_start();` if you're not already including it in your code.

Comment: In addition to Fred's comment, if you want to output something from a loop, do it in the loop (or cache).

Comment: as my new edit, i hope u may know my problem, u can ask me more if don't understand my question, Thank all ur welcome answer!

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand it correctly. Anyway try :

```
<td><a href="www.mynewlink.com?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">MyLink</a></td>
```

Make sure to start the session above your code.

Comment: you can md5($secret_code . $_SESSION['id']) then check it

Comment: `$secret_code` ?? `MD5` has can encrypt with secret code ??

Answer (score -1):

may be this can help :

```
<tr>
    <td class="noborder_dtable"><a href="business/index.php"><?php  echo $row_com['name_kh'];?></a></td>
    <td class="noborder_dtable"><a href="business/index.php"><?php echo $row_com['name_en'];?></a></td>
    <td class="noborder_dtable"><?php $_SESSION[]['id']=$row_com['id'];?></td>
</tr>
```